# Named Entity Recognition by dictionary in text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I need to extract keywords from text. I have a dictionary of keywords, let's say

```
apache-spark
java
pathon
amazon-web-services
apache-kafka
```

and I have a job post for example:

```
Design, develop and maintain ETL processing pipelines for data ingestion and sharing
Contribute to system architecture design discussions and improvements
Communicating with different teams regarding data quality, consistency and availability

Our technology stack:

GCP (BigQuery, GCS, PubSub, DataProc etc)
Spark, Kafka, Kudu
Airflow, dbt
Tableau
4+ years experience as a Data Engineer
Proven track record of working with SQL, Python, Airflow and Docker
Experience in large scale data processing (Apache Spark or similar) and Scala/Java is a big plus
Strong expertise in cloud-based data warehouses like Google BigQuery
Fluency in English verbal and written skills.
```

In the text we have `Apache Spark` keyword. My dictionary contains slightly different keyword  - `apache-spark`. The same is with `Kafka` - in my dictionary I have `apache-kafka`.

Will it be possible to extract such keywords from text with Stanford NER? Is it a task for Stanford NER or I'm on the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Having some sort of alias and synonyms for NER is definitely something that helps. Without it, it's hard for the model to guess unless a pre-trained model with the alias detecting already exists.

- https://aclanthology.org/W17-4405.pdf
- https://ebiquity.umbc.edu/_file_directory_/papers/955.pdf
- https://aclanthology.org/2021.naacl-main.118.pdf

But when it comes to computing terms, StackOverflow helps!

```
import requests
from  collections import defaultdict

terms = """apache-spark
java
pathon
amazon-web-services
apache-kafka""".split('\n')

alias = defaultdict(set)
related = defaultdict(set)

for t in terms:
  url = f"https://stackoverflow.com/tags/{t}/synonyms"
  response = requests.get(url)
  bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf8'))
  for a in bsoup.find_all('a', attrs={'rel': 'tag'}):
    if "show questions tagged" in a.attrs['aria-label']:
      alias[t].add(a.text)
    else
      related[t].add(a.text)

print(alias)
```

[out]:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'apache-spark': {'apache-spark',
              'spark',
              'spark-cluster-framework'},
             'java': {'.java',
              'core-java',
              'j2se',
              'java',
              'java-api',
              'java-libraries',
              'java-se',
              'javax',
              'jdk',
              'jre',
              'openjdk',
              'oraclejdk'},
             'amazon-web-services': {'amazon-web-services', 'aws'},
             'apache-kafka': {'apache-kafka',
              'kafka',
              'kafka-cluster',
              'kafka-partition',
              'kafka-topic'}})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will study these documents in detail!